# Select multiple columns from one table, get corresponding details from another table and insert these to another table

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Master Table: Has all detailed information like proper_ID and proper_Name and other fields.

Parent Table: Has the only ID for mother and father not there proper_ID and proper_Name

Child Table: Need to Insert proper_ID and proper_Name in the same order as a parent and avoid duplicate entries too.

```
Master_Table
---------------------------------------------------------------
Proper_ID | Proper_Name | Proper_Address | Proper_Phone |Proper_Zipcode
----------------------------------------------------------------
ABC_235 | Pansy Montgomery | 427 Preston Court| 1234| 5679
KWH_631 | Price Maxwell | 164 Conduit Boulevard| 8782| 7893
DEA_124 | Howard Kelly | 314 Agate Court| 3234| 1529
FAE_832 | Best Mcpherson | 325 Dorchester Road| 1582| 1861


Parent_Table
---------------------------------------------------
M_ID | F_ID | Picture_URL | Age_Group | Email
---------------------------------------------------
235| 832 | http://placehold.it/32x32| 45 | espinozastrickland@accruex.com
631| 124 | http://placehold.it/32x32| 50 | roycooke@concility.com

Output Expected:
Child_Table
---------------------------------------------------
Mother_ID | Mother_Name | Father_ID | Father_Name
---------------------------------------------------
ABC_235 | Pansy Montgomery | FAE_832 | Best Mcpherson
KWH_631 | Price Maxwell | DEA_124| Howard Kelly 


select mt.proper_id, mt.proper_name from master_table mt, parent_table pt
where mt.proper_id in (pt.m_id, pt.f_id)

proper_id | proper_name
-------------------------
ABC_235 | Pansy Montgomery
FAE_832 | Best Mcpherson
KWH_631 | Price Maxwell  
DEA_124| Howard Kelly
```

Comment: Are the `Proper_ID` values all of the form 3 letters, underscore, 3 digits?

Comment: Yeah, they are sometime range of 2 to 3 letters, underscore and range of 3 to 4 digits.

Comment: And the digits match the values in `Parent_Table`?

Comment: Yes, only the digit matches and parent_table will have unique digits and it never conflicts. 
proper_is is the unique key.

Comment: In certain scenarios for proper_id the letters might the be same but the digits are unique.

Comment: I would be tempted to first fix this schema design

Comment: There don't appear to be any children(in a biological sense here) Pansy montgomery's mother is pansy montgomery? And the numeric node on the master table always points to M_id?

Comment: @Salmon - I used random json generator to get the names. This was sample input haven't used the actual names or contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `Child_Table` with a [`CREATE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) statement. You need to `JOIN` the `Parent_Table` to the `Master_Table` twice, once to get the mother's details and once to get the father's details. Note that you should use ANSI join syntax, comma joins have been superseded for a long time.

```
CREATE TABLE Child_Table AS
SELECT m1.Proper_ID AS Mother_ID,
       m1.Proper_Name AS Mother_Name,
       m2.Proper_ID AS Father_ID,
       m2.Proper_Name AS Father_Name
FROM Parent_Table p
JOIN Master_Table m1 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(m1.Proper_ID, '_', -1) = p.M_ID
JOIN Master_Table m2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(m2.Proper_ID, '_', -1) = p.F_ID
```

Then you can

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Child_Table
```

Output:

```
Mother_ID   Mother_Name         Father_ID   Father_Name
KWH_631     Price Maxwell       DEA_124     Howard Kelly
ABC_235     Pansy Montgomery    FAE_832     Best Mcpherson
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94f42a1/1)

If you only want to generate one row for a given pair of `M_ID` and `F_ID` values, you can place a `UNIQUE` index on `Mother_ID, Father_ID` in `Child_Table` in the `CREATE` statement, and then either `IGNORE` duplicates or `REPLACE` them:

```
CREATE TABLE Child_Table (UNIQUE(Mother_ID, Father_ID)) IGNORE
... -- as above
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/292b5f/1)

Comment: I have master_table and parent_table, the output has to be into 3rd table(child_table)

Comment: This solves one part of the my query. If I encounter duplicate entry in parent table. Does it insert into child table? or update?

Comment: @JohnSmith If `M_ID` and `F_ID` are the same it will insert an identical entry. That behaviour can be modified if you don't want it...

Comment: I have multiple rows with picture url being different or email id being different but m_id and f_id are same.

Comment: Well those would create duplicate rows in `Child_Table`. Do you want that?

Comment: I need to avoid it and just take the latest one! Not sure that is possible. Then in this case I will have check based on createdat/udpateat date for updating the child_table

Comment: @JohnSmith you have no field in `Parent_Table` that can define "the latest one"

Comment: Sequelize the ORM by default creates createdAt, updatedAt fields when the model is initialized. We can use those I guess. Correct me if am wrong, we will have to loop through child table to check if those id exists and then either insert or update. Am not sure we same similar approach in SQL

Comment: Also, given that `Child_Table` is only generated from `M_ID` and `F_ID` then the resultant row will be exactly the same for a given `M_ID` and `F_ID` value, so it doesn't really matter. Or are you planning on copying other data into `Child_Table`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206622/discussion-between-john-smith-and-nick).